# Try Again Do-While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while, do-loops

It is a very simple program. The computer and user chooses a number between 0-3. I want the program to loop back if the user does not guess the same number as the computer.

```
    String input; // input is a string variable
    int cpucrazy;
    int convertstring;
```

// First Step //

```
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number between 0-3");
    convertstring = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

// Random section //

```
    Random ran = new Random ();
    cpucrazy = ran.nextInt(3);
```

// computation!

```
if (cpucrazy < convertstring) {
     JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Your guess is too high. Guess again?"); }


else if (cpucrazy > convertstring) {
     JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Your guess is too low. Guess again?"); }


else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!!");
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the problem that you faced.

Comment: You'll want to pick your random number _before_ asking for input, then ask for input, do your comparisons, and show your message dialog all within a `do { ... } while (convertstring != cpucrazy)` loop

Comment: The do-while loop did work as you mentioned. However, the computer changes the number when it loops. I want the computer to remember the number and allow the user to keep guessing.

Comment: @ninjacoder Look at my answer. You will see that to avoid the computer from picking a new number you have it pick a number *before* entering the loop. Inside the loop you only get input from the user and compare the two numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (cpucrazy < convertstring) {
 JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Your guess is too high. Guess again?"); }


else if (cpucrazy > convertstring) {
     JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Your guess is too low. Guess again?"); }


else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!!");
```

You need to put a while loop ( or some type of looping construct ) around the above code and exit the construct when: `cpucrazy == convertstring` or stay in the loop construct while `cpucrazy != convertstring`

The loop could look like the following pseudo-code:

```
b = random();

do
{
     input a;
     if( a != b )
     {
         if(a < b )
         {
              print "Too low";
         }
         else
         {
              print "Too high";
         }
     }
} while( a != b );

print "You got it correct"
```

Comment: @ninjacoder If my answer helped you, please 'accept' my answer. Glad to have been of help.